# FirebaseUI cancel button click callback

Tags: firebase, firebaseui

I'm trying to implement Firebase authentication. With the provided UI,

[image]

I can't figure out what method is called when the Cancel button is clicked. It don't seem to be documented, https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web.

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/786#issuecomment-744839593) there isn't a `cancelled` callback.

There is, however--[as also pointed out by bojeil-google](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/288#issuecomment-357342591) --, an undocumented `uiChanged` callback that could be hacked into capturing a cancelling state.

```js
const uiConfig = {
  callbacks: {
    uiChanged: function (fromPageId, toPageId) {
      console.log('uiChanged from:', fromPageId)
      console.log('uiChanged to:', toPageId)
    },
    uiShown: function() {
      console.log('ui is shown')
    },
  }
```

That did it for me.